# I am trying to get the keyboard to resign and start the timer countdown automatically when the user inputs 19 characters

Tags: swift, textfield, charactercount

Below is the code I am using to get the timer to fire and the keyboard to resign, this works great on the simulator. I type in 02272024075900 and it populates 02/27/2024 07:59:00 as soon as I type the last zero the keyboard resigns and the timer fires.

But when I run it on my handheld(same as simulator iPhone 15 Pro)device I have to add one extra tap on the keyboard to get it to work. I cannot understand why it works properly on all simulators, but not on my device.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    if textField == userInputTextField {

            if (userInputTextField?.text?.count == 2) || (userInputTextField?.text?.count == 5) {
                if !(string == "") {
                    userInputTextField?.text = (userInputTextField?.text)! + "/"
                }
            }
            if (userInputTextField?.text?.count == 10) {
                if !(string == "") {
                    userInputTextField?.text = (userInputTextField?.text)! + " "

                }
            }
            if (userInputTextField?.text?.count == 13) || (userInputTextField?.text?.count == 16) {
                if !(string == "") {
                    userInputTextField?.text = (userInputTextField?.text)! + ":"
                }
            }
        
            // Mark check the condition to not exceed 19 chars
            if let characterCount = textField.text?.count {
                // CHECK FOR CHARACTER COUNT IN TEXT FIELD
                if characterCount >= 19 {
                    startCountdown((Any).self)
                    // RESIGN FIRST RERSPONDER TO HIDE KEYBOARD
                    return textField.resignFirstResponder()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't need `if !(string == "") {` all places.. you can keep at the start itself... ***only once***

Comment: I removed the extra if !(string == "") and the code runs fine, same issue as far as a real device and the simulator. Thanks for helping me clean up the code Fahim.

Comment: Code seems fine... try to debug...

Comment: I added a print statement "19 reached" after startCountdown and ran the app on my device, it shows "19 reached" when I type a 20th character.

Comment: so if you type exact characters till 19, all is fine.. right?

Comment: Remember - `shouldChangeCharactersIn` is called before the text field has actually been updated. You are checking the count before the latest change is actually applied.

Comment: yes Fahim, all characters display correctly, it just won't fire the timer or resign the keyboard on device. Works perfect on simulators